# Event Retargetting of the Focus and Blur Events

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a custom Polymer element that is meant to represent a complex input type. It contains an actual `input` tag inside its Shadow DOM, like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-input">
  <template>
    <input type="text" on-blur="{{onBlur}}" on-focus="{{onFocus}}"/>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-input', {
      onBlur: ...,
      onFocus: ...
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Currently, `focus` and `blur` events are leaking to outside listeners when the user clicks between the internal input and other areas within the custom element. If you open the Dev Tools Console in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lecwq?editors=101), you'll see internal and external focus and blur events happening even when clicking between the input and the surrounding green area (which is all inside the custom element).

Is there no way to capture the `focus` and `blur` events inside my custom element so I can only fire them when actually focusing and blurring the entire custom element?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed a `tabindex` on my `polymer-element` tag:

```
<polymer-element name="my-input" tabindex="0">
```

[Here's a working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/weamC?editors=101) where the external `focus` and `blur` events only register when the entire element is focused and blurred.